If the values ​are the same, sort the rows
If the values ​​of rows A+B+C match the values ​​in rows D+E+F, bring rows D+E+F to the same row of A+B+C.
df is  :
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['02.04.2024','03.04.2024', '04.04.2024', '05.04.2024', '06.04.2024',],
                   "B":['01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00'],
                   "C":['1111', '1111', '1111', '1111', '1111'],
                   "D":['03.04.2024', '', '06.04.2024', '02.04.2024', ''],
                   "E":['02:00:00', '', '05:00:00', '01:00:00',''],
                   "F":['1111','', '1111', '1111','']})
print(df)
            A         B     C           D         E     F
0  02.04.2024  01:00:00  1111  03.04.2024  02:00:00  1111
1  03.04.2024  02:00:00  1111                            
2  04.04.2024  03:00:00  1111  06.04.2024  05:00:00  1111
3  05.04.2024  04:00:00  1111  02.04.2024  01:00:00  1111
4  06.04.2024  05:00:00  1111


df expected :

            A         B     C           D         E     F
0  02.04.2024  01:00:00  1111  02.04.2024  01:00:00  1111
1  03.04.2024  02:00:00  1111  03.04.2024  02:00:00  1111
2  04.04.2024  03:00:00  1111                            
3  05.04.2024  04:00:00  1111                            
4  06.04.2024  05:00:00  1111  06.04.2024  05:00:00  1111

All my attempts with e.g. mask, replace or sort were unsuccessful.




Can you have multiple exact matches? other columns?

Yes, there can be multiple exact matches in other columns

Then maybe clarify your example to illustrate that, I'll update my answer.

I haven't yet updated my answer (I was waiting for you to update the example). If you want to provide a reproducible example, use df.to_dict('tight') and pastes the output dictionary as [edit] to your question. If you have an error, please be explicit.

I found the error, the solution works great. Thank you for your effort.

Ps.: If I have many thousands of rows on the left and many hundreds of identical rows on the right, 'merge' becomes 'concat', the DataFrame is doubled in rows and the rows are not aligned.

This is expected, in this case you would need a merge with de-duplication, which is why I had requested an updated example. The exact way will depend on the exact data and expected logic.

Here is an updated example. Is that enough for your needs? (The index on the right means: these are the values ​​of columns AA to EE in the DataFrame)

This looks like you could use a merge after splitting the DataFrame in two and replacing the empty strings with NA:
df.replace('', pd.NA, inplace=True)

left = ['A', 'B', 'C']
right = ['D', 'E', 'F']
out = (df[left]
       .merge(df[right], left_on=left, right_on=right, how='outer')
       .dropna(how='all')
      )

out.fillna('', inplace=True)

Output:
            A         B     C           D         E     F
0  02.04.2024  01:00:00  1111  02.04.2024  01:00:00  1111
1  03.04.2024  02:00:00  1111  03.04.2024  02:00:00  1111
2  04.04.2024  03:00:00  1111                            
3  05.04.2024  04:00:00  1111                            
4  06.04.2024  05:00:00  1111  06.04.2024  05:00:00  1111


You can achieve this by iterating over each row and matching the values from columns A, B, and C with D, E, and F
import pandas as pd

# Initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['02.04.2024','03.04.2024', '04.04.2024', '05.04.2024', '06.04.2024',],
                   "B":['01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00'],
                   "C":['1111', '1111', '1111', '1111', '1111'],
                   "D":['03.04.2024', '', '06.04.2024', '02.04.2024', ''],
                   "E":['02:00:00', '', '05:00:00', '01:00:00',''],
                   "F":['1111','', '1111', '1111','']})

# Iterate through the DataFrame
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        # Check if A+B+C matches D+E+F
        if (df.loc[i, 'A'] == df.loc[j, 'D'] and
            df.loc[i, 'B'] == df.loc[j, 'E'] and
            df.loc[i, 'C'] == df.loc[j, 'F']):
            # If match is found, bring D+E+F to the corresponding row of A+B+C
            df.loc[i, 'D'] = df.loc[j, 'D']
            df.loc[i, 'E'] = df.loc[j, 'E']
            df.loc[i, 'F'] = df.loc[j, 'F']
            # Clear the original row
            df.loc[j, ['D', 'E', 'F']] = ''

# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)


I only get the first matching row (index 0) in 'D', 'E', 'F'. The others remain empty.
